# HTML canvas image from rgb values

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, rgb

I have three 12x12 arrays, each with R, G and B values. How would I go about outputting the image (12x12) using HTML Canvas? I've come across Canvas demos that show drawing lines and whatnot, but nothing like providing some RGB arrays to produce something.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `fillRect` method, described here : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillrect.asp

Each rectangle would match one table cell. You'd have to decide how large each of those rectangles would be : one pixel high and wide, or much more. Say we call this value `pixelSize`.

You create your canvas, get the context, define maxRows and maxColumns (here both would be 12).
Then you iterate with two nested loops :

```
for(row=0; row<maxRows; ++row) {
    for(column=0; row<maxColumns; ++column) {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + rTable[row][column] + ',' + gTable[row][column] + 
                           ',' + bTable[row][column] + ')';
        ctx.fillRect(column*pixelSize,
                 row*pixelSize,
                 pixelSize,
                 pixelSize);            
    }
}
```

Then draw the context...

(edited : changed rect into fillRect as per markE's remark)

Comment: +1 You're close but you need to fill each rect after you set the fillStyle. If you use ctx.fillRect instead of ctx.rect then your solution should work.  Alternatively, do ctx.beginPath, ctx.fillStyle, ctx.rect, ctx.fill inside the loop.

Comment: On the side, is it possible to save the image as a jpg or png or any other format?

Comment: Used http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/ for the saving. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks markE. Not too used to canvas art, as you see. :)

Answer (score 0):

The function below, if RGBA data of the form `[[123,32,40,255], [3,233,42,120], ...]`, will return a canvas with that data:

```js
function createCanvasFromRGBAData(data, width, height) {
  // `data` should look something like [[123,32,40,255], [3,233,42,120], ...]
  if(width*height !== data.length) throw new Error("width*height should equal data.length");
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let imgData = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    imgData.data[i*4+0] = data[i][0];
    imgData.data[i*4+1] = data[i][1];
    imgData.data[i*4+2] = data[i][2];
    imgData.data[i*4+3] = data[i][3];
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
  return canvas;
}
```

However, in your case, you have one 12x12 array for each of red, green and blue. In other words, your data is of "shape" `[C,W,H]`, buSo you need to transform your data first. I'll do a 3x3 example instead of 12x12 so it's easier to type:

```js
// an array of three 3x3 arrays:
let colorChannels = [
  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], // red
  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], // green
  [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]], // blue
];

let RGBA = [];
for(let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  for(let y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
    RGBA.push(colorChannels[0][x][y]); // red
    RGBA.push(colorChannels[1][x][y]); // green
    RGBA.push(colorChannels[2][x][y]); // blue
    RGBA.push(255); // alpha (transparency)
  }
}

let canvas = createCanvasFromRGBAData(RGBA, 3, 3);
```